# Existence of submultiplicative norm on a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, algebras

This is probably a very simple and maybe elementary question but, suppose we have a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}$ say $L$, is there always a sub-multiplicative norm on $L$, seen here as a finite $\mathbb{C}$-vector space ?

Comment: See this other question and its accepted answer.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26248/submultiplicative-matrix-norm-max-norm/26252

Comment: But how can we identify or link the matrix norm to a random $\mathbb{C}$-vector space ?

Answer (score 0):

Submultiplicativity is a property of matrix norms.  In particular, "$||Av|| \leq ||A||\,||v||$" and "$||AB|| \leq ||A||\,||B||$".  In your case, $A,B \in M^{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$.

If this is unclear, you may need to provide substantially more explanation about what you do and what you do not understand.

Comment: I want to show that there exist a norm $||.|| : x \longmapsto ||x|| $ on the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $L$ such that $\forall x,y$ in $L$ we have $||x.y|| \leq ||x||.||y||$

Comment: That would be an excellent clear definition of the problem to have in (edited into) your question.

Comment: @LeLoupSolitaire : Also, do you realize you are asking for the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)?

Comment: Oh i see... so the norm here is simply the one induced from the complex dot multiplication ? like the complex inner product ? i am having huge troubles with seeing this for some reason

Comment: I am trying to prove that $L$ is a Banach Algebra such that the exponential map

$exp : L \longrightarrow L$ such that 
           $X \longmapsto \sum \frac{X^n}{n!}$ is well defined and continuous. I know how to do that for matrices but i just can't see how to switch to that in my actual context...

Comment: @LeLoupSolitaire : Again, editing your question to accurately reflect (what you want to do, (2) what is working/what you understand, and (3) what is not working/what you do not understand will vastly increase the likelihood that you will get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{C} \subseteq L$ be a finite [extension of fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension). Then the extension $\mathbb{C} \subseteq L$ is [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension), since it is finite. But then we must have $L = \mathbb{C}$, since $\mathbb{C}$ is [algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field). The standard norm on $\mathbb{C}$ is submultiplicative.